# API call terminate when screen gets off (or app goes background) IOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, flutter-ios

I have a login page which starts downloading base data for the app after user enters username and password, and its a long duration operation like 2 or 3 minutes

In IOS at the middle of downloading data if screen gets off and locked, the operations terminates.

Here is the code
LoginPage part:

```
var repository = GlobalRestRepository();
var db = BasicDB();
List<basicModel> notDownloaded = await db.selectByLoaded(false);
for (int i = 0; i < notDownloaded.length; i++) {
    await repository.getBasic(notDownloaded.elementAt(i));
}
```

GlobalRestRepository part:

```
class GlobalRestRepository {
  final HttpClient http = HttpClient();

Future<void> getBasic(basicModel model) async {
    String url = "${Variables.mainUrl + basicModelUrl}";

    var response = await http.postExtraToken(url);
    .
    .
    .
 }
}
```

HttpClient part:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
...
class HttpClient {

  static final HttpClient _instance = HttpClient._privateConstructor();

  factory HttpClient() {
    return _instance;
  }

  Future<dynamic> postExtraToken(String path) async {
    Response response;
    try {
      response = await post(Uri.parse(path),
              headers: {"extra": Variables.extra, "token": Variables.token});
      final statusCode = response.statusCode;
      if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 299) {
        if (response.body.isEmpty) {
          return [];
        } else {
          return jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
        }
      } else if (statusCode >= 400 && statusCode < 500) {
        throw ClientErrorException();
      } else if (statusCode >= 500 && statusCode < 600) {
        throw ServerErrorException();
      } else {
        throw UnknownException();
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw ConnectionException();
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @Alilzadyar Did you found solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Wakelock](https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock) plugin, we can solve this problem, but I don't know this is the best solution or not.
Note: This plugin works for all the platforms except linux.

Add the below code in the screen where you are initiating the api request.

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    checkAndEnableWakeLock();
  }

  void checkAndEnableWakeLock() async {
    bool wakeLockEnabled = await Wakelock.enabled;
    if (!wakeLockEnabled) {
      Wakelock.enable();
    }
  }
```

Call disable method when all the api calls are completed.

```
Wakelock.disable();
```

Using above code you can avoid screen getting off issue.